# Android createScaledBitmap results in broken lines when scaling down

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a very simple App to scale down my drawings on screen.

After getting the drawing as a Bitmap (in 1080x1080), I used:

`Bitmap scaledDownBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 27, 27, false);`

to scale it down. However, if I dump the scaledDownBmp as a PNG file, what I discovered was that the line I drew became scattered points. I dumped the original bitmap file and there's no problem.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are scaling to a very small size in relation to the original size, so, in your case **from 1080x1080 to only 27x27**.

For such a big scale change, set the **[filter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))** parameter to **true** instead of **false**.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 27, 27, true);
```

- With **true**, it will use **bilinear filtering**, so it will produce a better quality image. Yet, don't expect something amazing at only 27x27.
- With **false**, it will use **nearest-neighbor scaling**, therefore the output for such a big scale change may appear as just dots. If the output image size was bigger it would show better.